# Get a specific value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to get a specific value from a repetition attribute during the conversion XML to XML using XSLT

Suppose I have this XML:

```
<SessionDetails>

 <SessionId>0</SessionId>
 <SessionTitle></SessionTitle>

 <HTMLUserActivity level="info"> [b]</HTMLUserActivity> 
 <HTMLUserActivitylevel="info">The value that I take "AAA" </HTMLUserActivity>
 <HTMLUserActivity level="info"> [b]</HTMLUserActivity> 
 <HTMLUserActivity level="info"> [br]</HTMLUserActivity>

 <Message Index="2">
   <Id>0x500A</Id>
   <Type>Error</Type>
   <Meaning>Group (0000) attribute not allowed as Additional attribute</Meaning>
 </Message>

 <HTMLUserActivity Level="Info">[CR][LF][font color="#000080"]</HTMLUserActivity>
 <HTMLUserActivity Level="Info">[CR][LF][tr]</HTMLUserActivity>
 <HTMLUserActivity Level="Info">[td align="center" valign="top" class="item" colspan="3"]</HTMLUserActivity>
 <HTMLUserActivity Level="Info">[b]</HTMLUserActivity>

</Sessiondetails>
```

I want to get the specific value (AAA) from a attribute

```
<HTMLUserActivitylevel="info">The value that I take "AAA" </HTMLuserActivity>
```

The output that I want to get only AAA, so far I tried to create below XSLT, but I couldn't get the the value:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/SessionDetails/HTMLUserActivity">
  <xsl:if test="contains(SessionDetails/HTMLUserActivity,'AAA')">
    <xsl:variable name="testName" select = "//SessionDetails/HTMLUserActivity"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I assume that I need to use `for-each` and `if` statement, but is there any better idea how to get the value?

Comment: *The value that I take "AAA"* is text, not an attribute. What would like to retrieve? The whole content of `<HTMLUserActivity>` tags that contain 'AAA'?

Comment: Actually I want to take only AAA as a value, I think I should do split the string, between "The value that I take" and "AAA"

Comment: So you're searching 'AAA', and you want to retrieve 'AAA'?? I think I don't understand clearly your search condition. Is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Okay, actually it's just for more practice since I really new with XSLT and want to explore more for-each and if statement in XSLT.
I think I will change the question, the value I need is only from a tag contains "AAA". Is it less complicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/SessionDetails/HTMLUserActivity[contains(., 'AAA')]">
    <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

it will output all the `<HTMLUserActivity>` textual content. I added a predication that will fetch only the relevant `<HTMLUserActivity>`, according to your condition.

The code you have created in your original post can't output anything because:

1. the `<xsl:for-each>` changes the contextual node you are working in. Thus your condition `contains(SessionDetails/HTMLUserActivity,'AAA')` will never be true, because you don't have any other tags in *HTMLUserActivity*.
2. you put your result in a variable, that can't be used out of the scope of the `<xsl:for-each>` (unless you have removed some code within the for-each)